# Thenables in Promise.all (ES6 and Bluebird)

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

Is this safety device necessary?

```
Promise.all([...].map((thenable) => Promise.resolve(thenable)));
```

Is it possible and safe to supply thenables to collection methods - `Promise.all`, `Promise.race`, etc? Any pitfalls?

The question concerns Bluebird, as well as polyfilled and all native ES6 promise implementations.

Comment: You can supply any thenable or value in the iterable you pass to `Promise.all()`.  You don't have to wrap them into promises yourself.  The implementation of `Promise.all()` will test to see if they are a thenable and if so, wait for their resolution, if not, the value will be the resolution.  See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jgf0xwhm/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not necessary and should be done by the promise implementation itself:

> The `all` function returns a new promise which is fulfilled with an
>   array of fulfillment values for the passed promises, or rejects with
>   the reason of the first passed promise that rejects. **It resolves all
>   elements of the passed iterable to promises as it runs this
>   algorithm.**

[ES2015 Specification, paragraph 25.4.4.1 Promise.all ( iterable )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all)

Phrased more accessible [by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Description):

> If something passed in the iterable array is not a promise, it's converted to one by `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the same applies to Bluebird. I was confused by the fact that `Promise` and thenable types are used interchangeably in [Bluebird docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html), and there's no mention of thenables/promise-likes.